# Change output console used by Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm writing a CLI C program and when debugging the program, VS2015 opens the program in the default Windows 7 cmd. I'd like to know if there's any way to launch the program when debugging in a 3rd party terminal (ideally cmder).

Thanks for any help!